# How do I debug unit tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: dnx, xunit.net, visual-studio-code, coreclr

As per title, how do I debug xunit tests using Visual Studio Code?

I can already run xunit from the command line using dnx test but I would like to debug these tests now.

I'm on Mac.

Thanks.

Update: here is the output of dnvm and dnx:

```
dnx test -debug
Debug support is not available in DNX Core.

dnvm list -detailed

Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias   Location
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----   --------
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          darwin                  ~/.dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx       default ~/.dnx/runtimes

dnvm version
1.0.0-rc2-15546
```

Answer (score 1):

`dnx -p path\to\project test -debug`

`-debug` should do it.

You can find that a couple ways

1. `dnx -p ./folder test -?`

-the `-?` gives you all the help for the command 'test'

2. or read through code...

https://github.com/xunit/dnx.xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.runner.dnx/CommandLine.cs

Best of luck.

Comment: getting: Debug support is not available in DNX Core.

Comment: What is the version of DNVM and the version of DNX that you are running? -->  'dnvm version' will give you that version and 'dnvm list' will show you what runtime versions you have install and which one is the one running.

Comment: The above link is returning a 404 as of this date.